# How to use javascript to filter table rows based on multiple sections of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have the following checkboxes in a form that allows me to show/hide rows in a table. Each section of checkboxes works fine, but how do I make one section check the status of the other section of checkboxes, so the logic filters based on all selections?

I hope you can see what I am trying to do based on my snippet of sample data:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#type :checkbox").click(function() {
    $("td").parent().hide();
    $("#type :checkbox:checked").each(function() {
      $("." + $(this).val()).parent().show();
    });
  });
  $("#fee :checkbox").click(function() {
    $("td").parent().hide();
    $("#fee :checkbox:checked").each(function() {
      $("." + $(this).val()).parent().show();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form name="repaymentcalc" id="myForm" action="">


  <section id="type">

    <p id="Mortgage Type">Mortgage Type</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t2" id="t2" checked/>2yr Fixed
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t3" id="t3" checked/>3yr Fixed
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t5" id="t5" checked/>5yr Fixed
    <br>

  </section>

  <section id="fee">

    <p id="Fee">Fee</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fee" value="fee" id="fee" checked/>Fee
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fee" value="nofee" id="nofee" checked/>No Fee
    <br>

  </section>

</form>

<table id="mortgagetable">

  <tbody>

    <tr class="product">
      <td class="t2">2yr Fixed</td>
      <td class="initialrate">1.29</td>
      <td class="fee">999</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="product">
      <td class="t3">3yr Fixed</td>
      <td class="initialrate">1.29</td>
      <td class="fee">999</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="product">
      <td class="t5">5yr Fixed</td>
      <td class="initialrate">1.29</td>
      <td class="fee">999</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="product">
      <td class="t2">2yr Fixed</td>
      <td class="initialrate">1.29</td>
      <td class="nofee">no fee</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="product">
      <td class="t3">3yr Fixed</td>
      <td class="initialrate">1.29</td>
      <td class="nofee">no fee</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="product">
      <td class="t5">5yr Fixed</td>
      <td class="initialrate">1.29</td>
      <td class="nofee">no fee</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Merge both the checkbox click handler similar to this below

```
$(":checkbox").click(function () {
    var typeVals = [],
        feeVals = [];

    $("tr").hide();
    $("#type :checkbox:checked").each(function () {
        typeVals.push($(this).val());
    });
    $("#fee :checkbox:checked").each(function () {
        feeVals.push($(this).val());
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < typeVals.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < feeVals.length; j++) {
            $('td.' + typeVals[i] + '~ td.' + feeVals[j]).closest('tr').show();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to solve the problem, it still will show rows that shouldn't appear when you unselect checkboxes in the second section?

Comment: What I want it to do is hide the rows unless both <td class="t2/3/5"> AND <td class="fee/nofee"> matches the checkbox selections. On loading, all of the checkboxes are ticked and so all rows show as would be expected. As checkboxes are unticked from either section, the rows should be checked and hide if the logic no longer is correct (i.e. one or other of the <td class> does not match that section of checkboxes. Whilst this appears to work at first, as soon as you untick a checkbox from the second section, ALL of the logic from the first section no longer applied. Does this make any sense?

Comment: I do have an ugly working example for you where it check for both sections to show results in the table.. Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sachin_puthran/se8qoacd/

Answer (score 0):

```js
function MortgageTypeCheckbox(row){
    var bHide = true;
    $('#type input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(){
        var chkValue = $(this).val();
        console.log(chkValue);
        if($(row).find('td.'+chkValue).length){
            bHide = false;
            return false;
        }
    });
    
    return bHide;
}
function FeeCheckbox(row){
    var bHide = true;
    $('#fee input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(){
        var chkValue = $(this).val();
        console.log(chkValue);
        if($(row).find('td.'+chkValue).length){
            bHide = false;
            return false;
        }
    });
    
    return bHide;
}
```

```html
<form name="repaymentcalc" id="calcform" action="">


<section id="type">

  <p id="Mortgage Type">Mortgage Type</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t2" id="t2" checked/>2yr Fixed<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t3" id="t3" checked/>3yr Fixed<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t5" id="t5" checked/>5yr Fixed<br>

</section>

<section id="fee">

  <p id="Fee">Fee</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fee" value="fee" id="fee" checked/>Fee<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fee" value="nofee" id="nofee" checked/>No Fee<br>

</section>

</form>
```